# Cannot apply padding-bottom to inner span element

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox, ionic3

*.scss*

```
div.playlist {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    div.playlist span {
        position: absolute;
        text-align: center;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        color: white;
        font-size: 20px;
        .span-icon {
            padding-bottom: 50px !important;
        }
    }
    div.playlist span:before {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
        height: 100%;
        content: '';
    }
```

*.html*

```
<div class="playlist">
  <span class="span-icon"><ion-icon name="ios-star-outline"></ion-icon></span>
  <span>{{data.text}}</span>
  <img [src]="data.imageUrl" [alt]="data.text" />
</div>
```

I need to give `padding-bottom: 50px` only to the first `span` element(i.e. `class="span-icon"`).I have tried like below.But it is not working.Can you tell me where is the issue?

```
 div.playlist span {
        position: absolute;
        text-align: center;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        color: white;
        font-size: 20px;
        .span-icon {
            padding-bottom: 50px !important;
        }
    }
```

*Rendered on the Browser:*

```
<ion-col class="col" col-6="">
        <playlist ng-reflect-data="[object Object]"><div class="playlist">
  <span class="span-icon"><ion-icon name="ios-star-outline" role="img" class="icon icon-md ion-ios-star-outline" aria-label="star outline" ng-reflect-name="ios-star-outline"></ion-icon></span>
  <span>My Favorites</span>
  <img src="./assets/images/img2.jpg" alt="My Favorites">
</div></playlist>
      </ion-col>
```

Comment: is it normal to have .span-icon nested inside span for scss???

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you? `span-icon` is a custom `class` which I have given. @Mindless

Comment: not inside html, but scss, you have .span-icon inside div.playlist span

Comment: I think you cascading your sass wrong, like @Mindless said, check your sass!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specified the SCSS incorrect. Please use the below. `.span-icon` is not a child of `span`, but of `.playlist`

```css
div.playlist {
  span {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  .span-icon {
    padding-bottom: 50px !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh..Perfect. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Move .span-icon out of span styles in CSS. As per your HTML, span-icon is applied to a span i.e. inside just a div not inside a span.